# Model in Blender GLSL to XNA HLSL

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, hlsl, glsl, blender

Is it possible to make model in Blender, with enabled GLSL, add multiple textures, etc, and then just load it in XNA, where's own HLSL? Will it work?

Answer (score 2):

In a word, No.
But to get you started, you will need to use custom export scripts in Blender (I export to FBX format), and a custom content pipeline processor if you want to import the GLSL/materials/effects. This sounds like a lot of work; but at least now you know what you're googling for.